# How to send email of specific Google Sheet data after Responded submit Google Form Answer

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

i would like to ask about how to send email of specific Google Sheet data after Responded submit Google Form Answer

the google sheet data is collected from multiple sheets and using conditional IF or VLOOKUP or maybe QUERY

i have more than 2 sheet, just say 4 sheets (can be more)
Sheet 1 : Database
Sheet 2 : Doc X
Sheet 3 : Doc Y
Sheet 4 : Doc Z

the detail is like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/77qBM.png

so i want to make script that do sending email automatically after responded submit the google form

in this case it would send email to JKL@GMAIL.COM
because of the secret code is ID-004
the email would be something like this

```
Hi here is your ID list :

DOCX-003
DOCY-003
DOCZ-003
```

if the data still 1 row ( ABC@GMAIL.COM ID-001 )
then it would send this

```
Hi here is your ID list :
DOCX-001
DOCY-001
```

thanks you for your insight

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your expected result?

Comment: @Tanaike I'm sorry for my poor english. Actually, I want to send email automatically after someone submit answer from my Google Form.

example:
1. open Google Form
2. hit submit
3. got respond data in google sheet
4. from the google sheet data, i want send email to them atomatically

Comment: @Tanaike my problem, i dont know how to translate google sheet formula to google script-app

Comment: High-level direction: Write a function that gets the form values on form submission. Find the id or the key that allows you to identify the email address within your DB tabs. Upon fidning it, run another function that sends the email to the related email address + other infos.